# C# WPF Affecting main thread from UserControl class

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a simple image viewer that loads images at start, creates Items with pulled SQL data and then creates Dictionary with all the Item parameters.

Then another method builds what's needed and fills StackPanel with UserControls (ITEM) that act as "links" to images.

Trying to add another image, from UserControl (NEW_ITEM) nested in View that is loaded to ContentControl in MainWindow.

```
public partial class fileUpload : UserControl
    {
        public fileUpload()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string PathSource = @"SOURCE";
        string PathToCopy = @"DESTINATION";



        private void Border_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            
            PathSource = FU_source.Text;
            if (!FU_fileName.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                MainWindow V = new MainWindow();
                V.LoadCollection(); //This seems to work, but the content on MainWindow stays visible.

                ////Copy Inserted Item
                File.Copy(PathSource,PathToCopy + FU_fileName.Text + ".png", true);
                
                ////Remove Item Preview From List
                ((ItemsControl)this.Parent).Items.Remove(this);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERR TEST", "ERR TEST HEADER");
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Running LoadCollection() method does work OK if it's called from the MainWindow but does not work if called from fileUpload Class. (Program seems to do what's needed, but the user control won't disappear.)

Basically, it should refresh the whole process and refresh/refill StackPanel with new items.

I have encountered this problem many times and I think that I'm missing a key part in this.

***TL;DR: I am trying to refresh MainWindows StackPanel with new Items, but the controls won't disappear if method taking care of this is called from UC Class.***

Comment: It isn't a good practice to refer the MainWindow from a UserControl. This makes it tight coupled and the UserControl cannot be used anywhere else. Also modifying controls from a UserControl on a MainWindow isn't the way to go.

Comment: `MainWindow V = new MainWindow();` Creates a new instance of your MainWindow. This instance is not same as the one that starts up. Most likely you need to `var V = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;` instead

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Alright, so using UC isnt the way to go here? I wanted to make it more interactive, user drags in new photos, they get added to ItemControl inside View.

Comment: @DenisNedved Sure UC can be used, instead of directly using the `MainWindow` you should write events which the MainWindow registers on. The rule is, **A parent communicates via methods of/to the child. The child communicates to the parent with events.**

Comment: @NawedNabiZada This helps and temporarily solves the problem, but as JeroenVanLangen said, it's not the best solution to do it like so from UC.

Comment: No Denis, @NawedNabiZada is right, don't create a new MainWindow. There is no best method, only better methods.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Does this method have some specific name? I would like to enlighten myself and try this instead of that what I have so far.

Comment: @DenisNedved I did searched, but didn't found anything useful. But take for example a button. When you click the button, it will raise the click event. The button can be reused on many different usercontrols. This way the button isn't dependend on any usercontrol.

Comment: Alright, I'll try on improving myself, maybe I can make this even better. Anyway, Naweds solution works like a charm and helped a lot. Thank you many!